# Why doesn't MySQL use indexes for subqueries?

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.7

This query takes forever to run (30+m - infinity).

```
select date, 
       sc, 
       ( select count(fingerprint_id) 
         from stats 
         where hit_date >= t.date 
           and hit_date < date_add('2020-01-20', interval 1 day) 
           and hit_type = 0 
           and fingerprint_id is not null ) as total_fingerprint
from ( select date(hit_date) as date, 
              sum(sc) as sc 
       from delayed_stats  
       where hit_date > date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) 
       group by date(hit_date) 
       order by hit_date) t;
```

The individual queries take 1s and 8s to run, but combined it never finishes. I expected 8-9s. If I replace `t.date` with the static '2020-01-20' then it takes 8s. Just replacing one static date with `t.date` cause the query to 'hang'. The minimum query which replicates this hanging is

```
select date, 
       (select count(fingerprint_id) from stats where hit_date >= t.date and hit_date < date_add(t.date, interval 1 day) and hit_type = 0 and fingerprint_id is not null) as total_fingerprint
from (select '2020-01-01' as date union select '2020-01-02' as date) t;
```

This is the query explanation:

```
+----+--------------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table         | partitions                                                                                                                                | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows      | filtered | Extra                                                  |
+----+--------------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | <derived3>    | NULL                                                                                                                                       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL |      7496 |   100.00 | NULL                                                   |
|  3 | DERIVED            | delayed_stats | NULL                                                                                                                                       | range | hit_date_idx  | hit_date_idx | 5       | NULL |      7496 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | stats         | p20180101,p20180201,p20180301,p20180401,p20180501,p20180601,p20180701,p20180801,p20180901,p20181001,p20181101,p20181201,p20190101,p20190201,p20190301,p20190401,p20190501,p20190601,p20190701,p20190801,p20190901,p20191001,p20191101,p20191201,p20200101,p20200201 | ALL   | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL | 316867000 |     1.00 | Using where                                            |
+----+--------------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.11 sec)
```

It doesn't appear to be using the hit_date index (`PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`hit_date`)`) on the subquery for `stats` table. My ultimate goal is to combine these two queries (`interval 30 day`):

```
select date(hit_date), 
       sum(sc) 
from delayed_stats 
where hit_date > date_sub(now(), interval 30 day) 
group by date(hit_date) 
order by hit_date;

select date(hit_date), 
       count(fingerprint_id) 
from stats 
where hit_date > date_sub(now(), interval 30 day) 
  and hit_type = 0 
  and fingerprint_id is not null 
group by date(hit_date) 
order by hit_date; -- 2m21s
```

When I see the query plan for the the 2nd query on `stats` table, then it shows the `possible_keys` as `PRIMARY,source_id,stats_bag_id_idx`. I tried another way to combine them, with a join, but that took 15m to run, when it should only take 2m.

```
select t.date, 
       sc, 
       fingerprint_count 
from ( select date(hit_date) date, 
              sum(sc) as sc 
       from delayed_stats 
       where hit_date > date_sub(now(), interval 30 day) 
       group by date(hit_date) 
       order by hit_date ) t 
join ( select date(hit_date) date, 
              count(fingerprint_id) as fingerprint_count 
       from stats 
       where hit_date > date_sub(now(), interval 30 day) 
         and hit_type = 0 
         and fingerprint_id is not null 
       group by date(hit_date) 
       order by hit_date ) t2 on t.date = t2.date;
```

Comment: *It doesn't appear to be using the hit_date index `(PRIMARY KEY (id,hit_date))` on the subquery for stats table.* This is obvious and expected. 1) The index with `hit_date` as a prefix needed (and the best way - create the calculated field `date(hit_date) AS date_hit_date VIRTUAL` and the index `(date_hit_date, sc)`). 2) Replace `where hit_date > date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)` with `WHERE DATE(hit_date) > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY`. 3) Remove `ORDER BY` from subquery - it is ignored anyway. 4) Rewrite from correlated subquery to JOIN.

Comment: Why would `sc` need to be in the index? The query with `sc` and `delayed_stats` table only takes 1s. It is the other query with `stats` table that is causing the delay (8s by itself, infinite time combined). Same for `where hit_date > date_sub()` - that is on delayed_stats table which only takes 1s to query and will eventually be run for `interval 30 day`s. What do you mean by #4? Rewrite as I did at the bottom?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.  Also, note that partition pruning failed, possibly implying that partitioning _hurt_ rather than _helped_ performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the last join example and was able to string together 8 different queries using this structure:

```
select date, sc, fc, fc10s, fc30s, ...
from (select date(hit_date) as date, ...) t
join (select date(hit_date) as date, ...) t2 on t.date = t2.date
join (...) t3 on t.date = t3.date
...
```

It took about 20m to run, which is OK for a report and less than I thought it would take.